# Double decimal number convert to HEX string

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to convert a decimal number(17592186044416) to hex string in MFC. AndI have tried to use

```
code 1:
double ftw = 0;
CString str;
str.Format(_T("%X"), ftw); //this will always be 0 in HEX

code 2:
char t1[100];
_itoa_s(ftw, t1, 16);// this will give me 80000000 in HEX
```

It seems like the str.Format(_T("%X"), ftw); and _itoa_s(ftw, t1, 16); function has the limit. Is there any other command that I can use to get the  17592186044416 to hex string?
Thank you.

Comment: How about using a `long long` variable and `%llX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to a 64-bit integer and then format using the `I64` qualifier in your format string:

```
double ftw = 17592186044416.0;

CString str;
str.Format(_T("%I64X"), (__int64)ftw);
```

For the example above, `str` will have the string `"100000000000"`

Comment: Where did you find documentation about the %I64 format specifier?

Comment: @sergiol [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx)